# Eclipse RCP - How to open Launch Configuration dialog

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to open Launch Configuration dialog (like when press mouse_right on project - run as - run configurations) in RCP app via command? or any other way, but command preferred.

Comment: I mean how to call this http://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_launch_ui.htm dialog?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you type '`ALT+SHIFT+F1`' on an 'Create, manage and run configurations', the [plug-in Spy](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/incubator/spy/) will tell you it is a [`LaunchConfigurationsDialog`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/debug/internal/ui/launchConfigurations/LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java.htm)

A quick search in the Eclipse sources indicates it is created through an [`DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/debug/ui/DebugUITools.java.htm#367)

```
     final int[] result = new int[1];
         Runnable JavaDoc r = new Runnable JavaDoc() {
             /**
              * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
              */
             public void run() {
                 LaunchConfigurationsDialog dialog = (LaunchConfigurationsDialog) LaunchConfigurationsDialog.getCurrentlyVisibleLaunchConfigurationDialog();
                 if (dialog != null) {
                     dialog.setInitialSelection(selection);
                     dialog.doInitialTreeSelection();
                     if (status != null) {
                         dialog.handleStatus(status);
                     }
                     result[0] = Window.OK;
                 } else {
                     dialog = new LaunchConfigurationsDialog(shell, DebugUIPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchConfigurationManager().getLaunchGroup(groupIdentifier));
                     dialog.setOpenMode(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.LAUNCH_CONFIGURATION_DIALOG_OPEN_ON_SELECTION);
                     dialog.setInitialSelection(selection);
                     dialog.setInitialStatus(status);
                     result[0] = dialog.open();
                 }
             }
         };
         BusyIndicator.showWhile(DebugUIPlugin.getStandardDisplay(), r);
         return result[0];
```

That should give you enough material to get started.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/stable/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/images/lcd.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I've found LaunchConfigurationsDialog and even openLaunchConfigurationsDialogOnGroup, but couldn't understand it's parameters. Source code made it clear. Damn, I was so close...

Answer (score 4):

Based on VonC's answer I did the following, where `config` just is my instance of `ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy` and `mode` is `"run"`:

```
DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialog(
                PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(),
                config,
                DebugUITools.getLaunchGroup(savedConfig, mode).getIdentifier(),
                null);
```